# Related data not saved when added after creation with EF Core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have POCO objects that are exposed through a repository that uses EF Core 6 to access a database. I can persist "parent" objects to the database and related data that is added to the parent object before creating is persisted successfully as well. However, when trying to add children (`SingleSimulationResult` objects) to a parent object (`SingleSimulation` objects) after it has been created, the children are not persisted to the database.

Here is the code that tries to add and save children to the parent object.

```cs
singleSim.AddResultsToSimulation(allResults);
Console.WriteLine($"# results: {singleSim.Results.Count}"); // # results: 2
await scopedRepository.Save();

var test = await scopedRepository.GetById(singleSim.Id);
Console.WriteLine($"# results test: {test.Results.Count}"); // # results: 0
```

SingleSimulation class (`BaseEntity` just defines an `Id` property):

```cs
public class SingleSimulation : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public double Capital { get; private set; }

    public List<List<double>> Returns { get; private set; }

    private readonly List<SingleSimulationStrategy> _strategies = new List<SingleSimulationStrategy>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<SingleSimulationStrategy> Strategies => _strategies.AsReadOnly();

    private List<SingleSimulationResult> _results = new List<SingleSimulationResult>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<SingleSimulationResult> Results => _results.AsReadOnly();

    public SingleSimulation()
    {

    }

    public SingleSimulation(string name, string description, double capital, List<List<double>> returns, List<SingleSimulationStrategy> strategies)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Capital = capital;
        Returns = returns;
        _strategies = strategies;
    }

    public void AddResultsToSimulation(List<SingleSimulationResult> results)
    {
        if (_results is null)
            return;

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            _results.Add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Repository class:

```cs
public class SingleSimulationRepository : ISingleSimulationRepository
{
    private SimulationDbContext _dbContext;
    public SingleSimulationRepository(SimulationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task Add(SingleSimulation entity)
    {
        await _dbContext.AddAsync(entity);
    }

    public async Task<SingleSimulation> GetById(int id)
    {
        return await _dbContext.SingleSimulations.FindAsync(id);
    }


    ...

    public async Task Save()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```cs
public class SimulationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SimulationDbContext(DbContextOptions<SimulationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SingleSimulation> SingleSimulations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SingleSimulationResult> SingleSimulationResults { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SingleSimulationStrategy> SingleSimulationStrategies { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Seed data and custom conversion functions
    }
}
```

Here's what I have tried (to no avail):

1. Using Fluent API to configure One-to-Many relationship for `Results` (using `.HasMany()`).

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SingleSimulation>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Results)
    .WithOne();
```

2. Using `AddRange()` to add result objects to the DB before adding them to the parent and finally saving to DB (`SaveChangesAsync`).
3. Using `Attach()` to start tracking result objects before adding them to the parent.
4. Using `Include()` when loading the parent object from the database before adding children and trying to save them.

It feels like I'm missing something small, but after scouring the docs and other sources I cannot find the problem. What do I need to do to get children added to the parent after the parent has already been created to actually save to the DB?

Comment: I'm not familiar with EF, but anyway, I don't see the child objects being added to the DB anywhere. I think you should google for an example.

Comment: @BentTranberg One of the examples I looked at ([Saving Related Data - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#adding-a-related-entity)) let's it look like you can just add objects to the parent's list and save and then EF takes care of the rest. I'm still an EF noob though, so there's probably some configuration or something I'm missing for this example to work.

Comment: It's not clear how `singleSim` gets saved by `scopedRepository.Save()`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are configuring your entity relationships? (Also, you don't need to use `AddAsync` unless you are taking advantage of EF Core HiLo https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2021/02/ef-core-use-hilo-algorithm-to-generate.html)

Comment: @GertArnold I've added the previously omitted `GetById` method that shows how the repository retrieves a singleSim from the DB context. If my understanding of EF is correct, EF tracks any changes to this singleSim object and then saves them when `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync` is called in the `scopedRepository.Save` method.

Comment: Can this explain the mystery? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: @T.vanSchagen There basically isn't any Fluent configuration code currently, which seems to work for the other child objects if they are added to the parent before the parent is initially saved. I have tried doing it using Fluent API config - I've edited the question to include the config I used (under point 1. of things I've tried).

Comment: @BentTranberg I set up my models according to the [Single navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property) section and have also tried using the [manual configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1) so unless I missed something, that page doesn't seem to have my answer unfortunately.

Comment: I think you may need to ensure your configuration is mapping the relationships to your private fields (_results) rather than the public read-only accessors.

Comment: @StevePy I tried to ensure that by using this line of code `modelBuilder.Entity<SingleSimulation>().Navigation(b => b.Results).HasField("_results").UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);` but this doesn't seem to fix the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging by printing the EF Core change tracker's `LongView`, I noticed that no changes are detected on the object (even if changing a simple string property). It turns out the problem was that the `singleSim` object I was modifying was returned from a different `dbContext` than the one used by the `scopedRepository`.

The model setup wasn't the problem after all. Even without the Fluent API config the setup works as intended (even with the read only collections and private backing fields).